# Presenting transparent modal UIViewController on iPad iOS 7

Tags: ios, ipad

I have an iPad app which supports all orientations and has a UITabBarController managing a set of view controllers. Rotation works as expected everywhere. Keep in mind my UITabBarController is the `.rootViewController` of my app's UIWindow.

I now go to present a UIViewController modally from my UITabBarController. It presents well, and the status bar moves in accordance with the device's orientation. However, my UIViewController's view frame never changes (it is always in portrait dimensions, regardless of how it was presented).

This isn't an issue on iOS 8, and I thought UITabBarController would handle a modal controller on its own. Is there something I'm missing?

Bonus: ultimately this UIViewController will be transparent and reveal the app beneath it. When I try this and rotate my device, none of the regular view controllers rotate.

Answer (score 0):

> However, my UIViewController's view frame never changes (it is always in portrait dimensions, regardless of how it was presented).

This is expected.  In iOS 7, rotation was implemented by applying a transform to the top-level view controller's view.  The application of this transform does not alter the frame, which remains in portrait dimensions.  In iOS 8, rotation is implemented at the window level.

> Bonus: ultimately this UIViewController will be transparent and reveal the app beneath it. When I try this and rotate my device, none of the regular view controllers rotate.

The UIModalPresentationStyleFullscreen presentation style removes the presenter's view from the window while it is covered by the presented view controller.  If you modify the alpha of the presented view controller's view, you'll just see black underneath.

Since UIModalPresentationStyleOverFullscreen did not exist in iOS 7, you would need to use UIModalPresentationStyleCustom with your own transition animator.  Unfortunately, custom transitions with view controllers that can rotate is *extremely* buggy in iOS 7.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Not sure why I didn't think of this earlier, but I've ended up ditching the modal presentation technique and just gone for a child view controller system which seems to work better. Nevertheless a shame that these sorts of issues still remained until iOS 7.